# Recover mysql databases from LAMP

Tags: mysql, xampp, lampp

I had one lampp installation and now my Ubuntu is not working and bounces back to login screen again and again.

I have a dual boot set-up so I can access Windows 7 and I have mounted the Linux partition on it.

I have databases created with LAMP and is it possible to access this data from windows. Actually where is the MySQL data is stored ? IF I copy that files to XAMPP installation it will recover the databases ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table files are located in `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/[db_name]/` where `[db_name]` is the name of the database.

If you are using [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) you have to copy 3 files per table :

> Each MyISAM table is stored on disk in three files. The files have
>   names that begin with the table name and have an extension to indicate
>   the file type. An .frm file stores the table format. The data file has
>   an .MYD (MYData) extension. The index file has an .MYI (MYIndex)
>   extension.

If you are using [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-table-and-index.html) unfortunately you cannot move them:

> When MySQL drops a table or a database, it has to delete one or more
>   .frm files as well as the corresponding entries inside the InnoDB data
>   dictionary. Consequently, you cannot move InnoDB tables between
>   databases simply by moving the .frm files.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. I have just copied the database and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I found lampp databases inside

```
/opt/lampp/var/mysql/DATABASE_NAME
```